# Case Insensitive query taking advantage of index

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

I have tried several ways of making a case-insensitive query on mongo. My ideal scenario is to use a case insensitive index, which is clearly [documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/). The Problem is that I need the query to find from within the collection, values starting with a specific phrase, while not being case insensitive. The method that I have found that effectively achieves this is using a regex, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

> Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.

Furthermore, text indexes will **NOT** satisfy my needs , as according to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-query-operator-behavior)

> For case insensitive and diacritic insensitive text searches, the $text operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match. However, blueberry or blueberries will match.

Is there a way of achieving the desired functionality while making use of indexes, or a way that I could optimize my database to achieve this? The field in question is a short string limited to 30 characters

Comment: Can you provide some sample documents and queries?

Comment: Downcase the value into a new field, search by that field.

Comment: You would like to simultaneous perform 2 comparisons with a single field, one being a case-insensitive match of the entire string, and the second being a case-sensitive prefix match?

Comment: @Joe that's accurate